# how can I insert date into table where it's null and date is by default sysdate in timestamp fomat?

Tags: oracle, date, insert, timestamp

```
Name         Null     Type         
------------ -------- ------------ 
ID           NOT NULL NUMBER       
NAME                  VARCHAR2(20) 
ADDRESS               VARCHAR2(20) 
CLASS                 VARCHAR2(10) 
DATE_CREATED          TIMESTAMP(6)
```

---

```
1   SATISH  PUNE    SOFTWARE 
2   ABHISHEK    INDORE  BUSINESS    
3   ARUN    BARWANI GOVERNMENT  
4   RITESH  SHIVNI  SOFTWARE    
5   NAYAN   BANGLORE    SOFTWARE    27-12-19 07:23:45.000000000 PM
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking.  Please edit your question to clarify exactly what you are trying to do, including code that you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to `select` from your table including `systimestamp` for null values then use following `select`:

```
Select id, name, address, class,
       Nvl(date_created, systimestamp)
  From your_table;
```

If you want to `update` the date_created in table then use following `update`:

```
Update your_table
   Set date_created = systimestamp
 Where date_created is null;
```

Cheers!!